# Is this legitimate use of "undefined" or are there better approaches to this?

Tags: mysql, haskell

I've been playing around with MySQL-Simple lately. Trying to come up with some comprehensive examples to that library. I wanted to separate IDs from the actual record I'm trying to store.
To implement the error case for QueryResults for this Entity datatype I need the amount of fields this datatype actually consumes. Therefore I introduced an `Arity` Typeclass (which is pretty easy to get wrong, especially when the data changes). I'm also using `undefined` here to call the correct instance of the `arity` method.

I've seen something like this in several examples and yet I feel uneasy about the use of `undefined` here. Are there better ways to do that?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where

import Database.MySQL.Simple
import Database.MySQL.Simple.QueryResults
import Database.MySQL.Simple.QueryParams
import Database.MySQL.Simple.Result
import Database.MySQL.Simple.Param

connectInfo :: ConnectInfo
connectInfo = defaultConnectInfo { connectUser = "dbuser" }

data Person = Person { personName :: String
                     , personAge  :: Int
                     } deriving Show

class Arity a where
  arity :: a -> Int

instance Arity Person where
  arity _ = 2

instance QueryResults Person where
  convertResults [fname, fage] [vname, vage] =
    Person name age
      where
        !name = convert fname vname
        !age  = convert fage vage

  convertResults fs vs = convertError fs vs 2

instance QueryParams Person where
  renderParams (Person name age) = [render name, render age]

data Entity a = Entity Int a

instance (Arity a, QueryResults a) => QueryResults (Entity a) where
  convertResults (fid:fs) (vid:vs) =
    Entity id value
      where
        !id    = convert fid vid
        !value = convertResults fs vs

  convertResults fs vs =
    convertError fs vs (1 + arity (undefined :: Person))
```

Kind regards, raichoo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `arity` should only depend on the choice of `a`, i.e. its type, you should use a [Proxy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.7.2/docs/Data-Proxy.html) which is basically `()` with a phantom type tag:

```
class Arity a where
    arity :: proxy a -> Int
```

This way, instances of `Arity` are forced to not try to look at the passed value, and clients don't need to pass a bottom:

```
instance Arity Person where
    arity _ = 2

convertResults fs vs =
  convertError fs vs (1 + arity (Proxy :: Proxy Person))
```

Comment: Note how by using `proxy a` instead of `Proxy a` in the type of `arity`, we allow clients to use whatever representation of proxies (even something like `Nothing :: Maybe Person` would work), but parametricity still ensures that `arity` overrides can't use more information than just the type.

Comment: That's even better :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's fine. If you want a non-`undefined` alternative, you can use a proxy phantom type:

```hs
data Proxy a = Proxy

class Arity a where
  arity :: Proxy a -> Int

instance Arity Person where
  arity _ = 2

convertResults fs vs =
    convertError fs vs (1 + arity (Proxy :: Proxy Person))
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh Proxy! How could I forget about that one :D Thank you :)

Comment: @raichoo: easily, as proxies are ugly! You certainly shouldn't define `Proxy` yourself. Either use [the standard implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Proxy.html), or write lowercase `proxy` as suggested by Cactus, or – IMO best – don't make it a function type at all, but use [`arity :: Tagged a Int`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.7.3/docs/Data-Tagged.html#t:Tagged).

Comment: And it's also possible to recover the original definition of `arity`: `getProxy :: a -> Proxy a; getProxy x = Proxy`; `original_arity :: Arity a => a -> Int; original_arity x = arity (getProxy x)`. So `original_arity (Person "a" 3)` equals `2`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I certainly would not define `Proxy` myself. I know about `Data.Proxy` ^^. Anyway, thanks.